# 2 corosync nodes not online together (one offline, one online)

Tags: pacemaker, corosync, openais

I am currently trying to set up corosync based on this tutorial:

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-an-active-passive-postgresql-cluster-with-pacemaker-corosync-and-drbd-centos-5.5-p3

However, I am not able to get my 2 nodes connected.

I have 2 nodes:

```
data-master with IP address LAN: 10.0.0.122, Crossover: 172.16.0.1
data-slave with IP address LAN: 10.0.0.123, Crossover: 172.16.0.2
```

And this is my /etc/corosync/corosync.conf (exactly same as the tutorial):

compatibility: whitetank

```
totem {
   version: 2
   secauth: off
   threads: 0
   interface {
       ringnumber: 0
       bindnetaddr: 10.0.0.0
       mcastaddr: 226.94.1.1
       mcastport: 4000
   }
}

logging {
   fileline: off
   to_stderr: yes
   to_logfile: yes
   to_syslog: yes
   logfile: /tmp/corosync.log
   debug: off
   timestamp: on
   logger_subsys {
      subsys: AMF
      debug: off
   }
}

amf {
   mode: disabled
}
aisexec {
   user: root
   group: root
}
service {
   # Load the Pacemaker Cluster Resource Manager
   name: pacemaker
   ver: 0
}
```

I am able to start the openais service successfully. But, when I checking with `crm_mon -1` on both nodes, they have different result:

Node 1 (data-master)

```
Last updated: Tue Feb 25 19:24:48 2014
Last change: Tue Feb 25 18:49:19 2014 by root via cibadmin on data-master
Stack: classic openais (with plugin)
Current DC: data-master - partition WITHOUT quorum
Version: 1.1.9-2db99f1
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
0 Resources configured.


Online: [ data-master ]
OFFLINE: [ data-slave ]
```

Node 2 (data-slave)

```
Last updated: Tue Feb 25 19:25:10 2014
Last change: Tue Feb 25 18:47:17 2014 by root via cibadmin on data-master
Stack: classic openais (with plugin)
Current DC: data-slave - partition WITHOUT quorum
Version: 1.1.9-2db99f1
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
0 Resources configured.


Online: [ data-slave ]
OFFLINE: [ data-master ]
```

What I expect is to get both nodes online together:

```
Online: [ data-master data-slave ]
```

Can you guys help me out what exactly I missed?

My platform: VirtualBox, both Nodes are using SLES 11 SP3 with HA-Extension, both Guest IP Address for LAN is bridged, the Crossover is internal network mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need to switch to **unicast** from **multicast** communication.

Try something like this in your corosync.conf:

```
totem {
        version: 2
        secauth: off
        interface {
                member {
                        memberaddr: 172.16.0.1
                }
                member {
                        memberaddr: 172.16.0.2
                }
                ringnumber: 0
                bindnetaddr: 172.16.0.0
                mcastport: 5405
        }
        transport: udpu
}
```

Comment: This one's worked! Now `crm_mon -1` showing `Online: [ data-master data-slave ]` ! Thanks!