# Two nodes of corosync are offline

Tags: corosync

I saw: [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/578141/2-corosync-nodes-not-online-together-one-offline-one-online).

192.168.2.0/24 - Office net with GW *.*.2.1

According to the Corosync documentation, if the local interface is 192.168.5.67 with netmask 255.255.255.0, set bindnetaddr to 192.168.5.0.

**corosync.conf**

```
totem {
        version: 2
        crypto_cipher: none
        crypto_hash: none
        interface {
                ringnumber: 0
                bindnetaddr: 192.168.2.0
                mcastaddr: 239.255.1.1
                mcastport: 5405
                ttl: 1
        }
}
logging {
        fileline: off
        to_stderr: no
        to_logfile: yes
        logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
        to_syslog: yes
        debug: off
        timestamp: on
        logger_subsys {
                subsys: QUORUM
                debug: off
        }
}
quorum {
        provider: corosync_votequorum
}
service {
name: pacemaker
ver: 1
}
nodelist {
        node {
                ring0_addr: KVM-1
                nodeid: 1
        }
        node {
                ring0_addr: KVM-2
                nodeid: 2
        }
        node {
                ring0_addr: KVM-3
                nodeid: 3
        }
}
```

**crm status**

```
Stack: corosync
Current DC: KVM-1 (version 1.1.13-10.el7_2.2-44eb2dd) - partition WITHOUT quorum
3 nodes and 0 resources configured

Online: [ KVM-1 ]
OFFLINE: [ KVM-2 KVM-3 ]
```

**tcpdump log**

```
[oneadmin@KVM-1 corosync]$ sudo tcpdump -i ovs-br0 -n port 5405    
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ovs-br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
20:17:15.561824 IP 192.168.2.67.hpoms-dps-lstn > 239.255.1.1.netsupport: UDP, length 87
20:17:15.864866 IP 192.168.2.67.hpoms-dps-lstn > 239.255.1.1.netsupport: UDP, length 87
20:17:16.167969 IP 192.168.2.67.hpoms-dps-lstn > 239.255.1.1.netsupport: UDP, length 87
20:17:16.471014 IP 192.168.2.67.hpoms-dps-lstn > 239.255.1.1.netsupport: UDP, length 87
20:17:16.774051 IP 192.168.2.67.hpoms-dps-lstn > 239.255.1.1.netsupport: UDP, length 87
20:17:17.077136 IP 192.168.2.67.hpoms-dps-lstn > 239.255.1.1.netsupport: UDP, length 87
20:17:17.380149 IP 192.168.2.67.hpoms-dps-lstn > 239.255.1.1.netsupport: UDP, length 87
20:17:17.683214 IP 192.168.2.67.hpoms-dps-lstn > 239.255.1.1.netsupport: UDP, length 87
```

All nodes must be in online status? Where I have a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying multicast communication, which requires support on the underlying network. For three nodes, I think safest bet is to switch to `unicast` (aka normally sending to each host's own IP address 192.168.2.x).